# webview zoom controls

Tags: android, webview, zooming

I have a webview that you can navigate to an embeded link in it.  That link is to an image, and I enable zooming when navigating to that image, and disable it when the user goes back.  This works fine, except for the zoom controls.  For some reason they linger for a little bit when I come back, and this allows the user to mess with the zoom level of a webview that is not intended to be zoomed.  Once they fade away they dont come back, i just need some way to immediately disable them, rather than wait for them to fade.  Any answers?

I disable zooming like this:

```
contentView.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(false);
contentView.getSettings().setSupportZoom(false);
contentView.getSettings().setBuiltInZoomControls(false);
```

Edit:

This is also causing a crash when i try to go back to the previous activity when the controls are still showing.  Here is a crash dump from it if it helps fix either problem

```
FATAL EXCEPTION: main
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Receiver not registered: android.widget.ZoomButtonsController$1@47979810
    at android.app.ActivityThread$PackageInfo.forgetReceiverDispatcher(ActivityThread.java:859)
    at android.app.ContextImpl.unregisterReceiver(ContextImpl.java:869)
    at android.content.ContextWrapper.unregisterReceiver(ContextWrapper.java:331)
    at android.widget.ZoomButtonsController.setVisible(ZoomButtonsController.java:404)
    at android.widget.ZoomButtonsController$2.handleMessage(ZoomButtonsController.java:178)
    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:143)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5073)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:521)
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:858)
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:616)
    at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

Edit2:

Heres some of the code, not sure how much this helps

In the activity's onCreate function

```
contentView = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.message_content);
contentView.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient()
{
    @Override
    public void onPageFinished(WebView view, String url )
    {
        if ( !url.startsWith("http") )
        {
            view.clearHistory();
        }
        else
        {
            contentView.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
            contentView.getSettings().setSupportZoom(true);
            contentView.getSettings().setBuiltInZoomControls(true);
            topButton.setText("Go back");
            topButton.setOnClickListener(backClick);
        }
    }

    @Override
    public boolean shouldOverrideUrlLoading( WebView view, String url )
    {
        view.loadUrl(url);              
        return true;
    }
});
```

And this is how I go back from the zoom-able page

```
@Override
public boolean onKeyDown( int keyCode, KeyEvent event )
{
    if ( keyCode == KeyEvent.KEYCODE_BACK )
    {
        if ( contentView.canGoBack() )
        {
            contentView.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(false);
            contentView.getSettings().setSupportZoom(false);
            contentView.getSettings().setBuiltInZoomControls(false);
            topButton.setText("Add a comment");
            topButton.setOnClickListener(postClick);
            contentView.goBack();
            return true;
        }
    }
    return super.onKeyDown(keyCode, event);
}
```

Comment: I added some code, not sure if it is what you were looking for or if it helps at all...

Answer (score 0):

You could always disable the built-in zoom controls and implement your own.